# How to use TLS in Go ReverseProxy?

Tags: ssl, go, reverse-proxy

I have sites `https://a-b-c.com` and `https://www.x-y-z.com` running behind a reverse proxy on ports `4444` and `5555` respectively.

I had them configured to use letsencrypt tls certificates, but now I get an error when using the reverse proxy and I think I need to use a `&tls.config{}` that includes their certificates but I don't know how to set it up.

My ReverseProxy looks like:

```
  director := func(req *http.Request) {                        
    log.Println(req.Host)                                      
    switch req.Host {                                          
    case "a-b-c-.com":                                 
      req.URL.Host = "localhost:4444"                        
      req.URL.Scheme = "https"                                 
    case "x-y-z.com":                                   
      req.URL.Host = "localhost:5555"                           
      req.URL.Scheme = "https"                                                                                   
  }                                                            
  proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}          
  proxy.Transport = &http.Transport{                           
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,                          
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{                                        
      Timeout:   30 * time.Second,                             
      KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,                             
    }).Dial,                                                   
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,                     
    TLSClientConfig:     &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
  }                                                            

  log.Fatalln(http.ListenAndServe(":443", proxy))
```

Comment: I have written a reverse proxy that demonstrates how to do this (168 lines of code): https://github.com/hartsfield/go_proxy

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set up your reverse proxy. What you need to do is to set up HTTP server that you attach your reverse proxy to.

Configure TLS listener by passing two pairs of cert/keys:

```
abcCrt, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("a-b-c.crt", "a-b-c.key")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

xyzCrt, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("x-y-z.crt", "z-y-z.key")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

tlsConfig := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{abcCrt, xyzCrt}}
ln, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":443", tlsConfig) 
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

http.Serve(ln, proxy)
```